# foreach too slow with Blade in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am working with Laravel 5.2 and I have a section which is responding too slow, I have detected that the big delay occurs in a foreach loop, it takes one second per row and I am listing around 100 registers which makes the site very slow. It's rare because I am displaying only 7 columns and the table has in total 213 rows which is very little having the table 16 columns.

What can I do? This is the foreach block. It takes that long only running in the production environment

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
          <tr>
            <td>
              {{ $ticket->id }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ $ticket->creator->worksAt->nombre }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ $ticket->patient->toArray()['rut'] }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ $ticket->getProcessName() }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ $ticket->created_at->format('d M Y') }}
            </td>
            @if ($ticket->getProcessSla() == $ticket->getLatency() )
              <td  class="alert-warning">
            @elseif ($ticket->getProcessSla() < $ticket->getLatency() )
              <td  class="alert-danger">
            @else
              <td  class="alert-success">
            @endif
              {{ $ticket->getLatency() }} días
              (Límite: {{ $ticket->getProcessSla() }})
            </td>
            <td>
              @if ( null !== Auth::user()->roles->find($ticket->getProfileId()) )
                {{ Form::open(array('action'=>'StageController@redirect')) }}
                  {{ Form::hidden('ticket_id', $ticket->cryptId()) }}
                  {{ Form::hidden('process_id', $ticket->cryptProcessId()) }}
                  {{ Form::submit('Iniciar', ['class'=>'btn btn-xs btn-block btn-primary']) }}
                {{ Form::close() }}
              @endif
            </td>
          </tr>
    @endforeach
```

The ticket's model is this one

```
 <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Crypt;
use DB;

class Ticket extends Model
{


protected $fillable = [
  'patient_id',
  'id_empresa',
  'id_usuario',
  'requiere_clinico',
  'requiere_ept',
  'activo',
  'responsable',

  'ept_id',
  'clinico_id',
  'is_massive',
  'inasistente',

  'creacion_original',
  'ficha_id'

];




/*
 * Relations
 */
public function creator()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id_usuario');
  //'App\Partner', 'clinical_provider', 'id_client', 'id_provider'
}


public function assignedTo()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'responsable', 'id');
}

public function appointment()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Appointment', 'id_ticket');
}

public function annulments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Anullment');
}

public function eptCriteria()
{
  return $this->hasOne('App\EptCriteria');
}


public function patient()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient');
}

public function enterprise()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Enterprise', 'id_empresa');
}

public function process(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Process', 'flows', 'id_ticket', 'id_proceso');
}

public function witness(){
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Witness')->withTimestamps();
}

public function documents()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Document', 'id_ticket');
}

public function flows()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Flow', 'id_ticket');
}

public function comments()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Tickets\Comment', 'ticket_id');
}

/**
 * Esto permite dejar la evidencia de cuando se envió el contacto a las empresas
 * @return [type] [description]
 */
public function enterpriseContacts(){
  return $this->hasMany('App\Enterprisecontact');
}

public function getProcessName(){
  return \App\Process::find($this->process()->max('id_proceso'))->nombre;
}

public function getProcessDescription(){
  return \App\Process::find($this->process()->max('id_proceso'))->descripcion;
}

public function getProfileId(){
return \App\Process::find($this->process()->max('id_proceso'))->id_perfil;
}

public function getProcessSla(){
  return \App\Process::find($this->process()->max('id_proceso'))->sla;
}

public function getLatency(){
  $created = new \Carbon\Carbon($this->created_at);
  return $created->startOfDay()->diffInDays();
}
public function getProcessId(){

  return \App\Process::find($this->process()->max('id_proceso'))->id;
}

public function getClinicalAppointment(){
  return $this->appointment()->where('tipo_citacion', '=', 1)->first()['fecha'];
}


public function cryptProcessId(){
  return  Crypt::encrypt($this->getProcessId());
}

public function cryptId(){
  return  Crypt::encrypt($this->id);
}

public function scopeMassive($query){
  $query->where('activo', 1)
        ->where('is_massive', 1);
}

public function eptTest()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\EptTest');
}

public function clinicalMovements()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\MR\Movimiento');
}


 }
```

Comment: post your code. Foreach is not slow, your code block inside it may be the problem

Comment: Please add your Ticket model source code.

Comment: To determine if it is the `@foreach` that is slow remove all of the code between `@foreach` and `@endforeach` then refresh your page.

Comment: +1 to all previous comments. Also, at first glance, it looks like you could be suffering performance lags with your relations (`->creator`, `->patient`). Look into [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) -- TLDR it combines what would be otherwise separate database requests into a single one. Common Laravel pitfall.

Comment: I'd also look into changing the getProcessSla() method. You're doing a database call for every use of that.

Answer (score 4):

Let's count the number of queries and other ops here:

1. `$ticket->creator`: query
2. `creator->worksAt` probably another query (guessing as source code not provided)
3. `$ticket->patient`: query
4. `$ticket->getProcessName()`: query
5. `$ticket->getProcessSla()`: query
6. `Auth::user()->roles`: query
7. `$ticket->cryptId()`: Encryption
8. `$ticket->cryptProcessId()`: Encryption + query (for finding process)

In total: 7 queries + 2 encryptions per ticket times 213 rows.

Equates to **1,491 queries and 426 encryptions**. No wonder it's slow? It's not foreach.

You need to optimize by [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading), [pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination), persistent storage (for encryptions) and memoization (instead of repeatedly finding the same process model multiple times in the database).